# Windows 8.1 Text Showing Up as Random Artifacts

Tags: windows-8.1, troubleshooting

I had this very random and very debilitating bug occur in Windows 8.1 today and wanted to document it so others can learn how to fix it and maybe someone knows how to prevent it that can provide some advice.

Upon starting my PC, all of my text looked like this picture: [image: Windows 8.1 text artifacts]

The only thing I know that happened before this is that I tried to install a ttc (Avenir Next Condensed.ttc) font to be used with a Photoshop design file that upon clicking "Install", windows said "this file does not appear to be a valid font". It should be noted that this font was installed on another computer before being transferred to mine (ie it works on another computer, not Windows 8.1, though.)

It also appears this could be a bug related to Visual Studio 2013. (My entire project was missing. - Fortunately, I checked in my code before turning it off... Thank god...)

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/d77274a2-bb0a-4dfa-b4ab-a83d195940d6/windows-7-symbols-instead-of-text?forum=w7itprogeneral Shows a solution of copying over fonts from another computer as well as others experience this issue seemingly at random.

To see this bug in action: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=525yPBGEfjU

Comment: Have you tried uninstalling the font that you put on your computer?

Comment: @HelpingHand: The font isn't installed. Windows failed during the installation. However, when I go to the fonts folder, there are only three listings of font files. Although I have no idea what they are since it's all gibberish. I could try to post the font file online later, but I don't know if that would be some form of illegal distribution of copyrighted material.

Comment: Yeah, that would be illegal. Just link to the file if you must. Are you sure that it was not a virus?

Comment: @HelpingHand: I've scanned it with a variety of software and it was taken from the installed fonts on another computer. Which I know doesn't mean it isn't a virus, but it seems much more like a bug.

Comment: The thread [Windows 8.1 missing font files after restart](http://superuser.com/questions/695635/windows-8-1-missing-font-files-after-restart) contains a few ideas that you could try.

Comment: @harrymc This looks promising, I will have a look at this tonight.

Comment: @harrymc The link you posted to did in fact solve the problem. I can't give bounty to a comment and I apparently can't upvote since I bounty'd all my user reputation away. Perhaps you can post it as an answer.

Comment: Done as requested.

Comment: Windows 8.1 - Legend of Zelda Edition

Comment: Thanks for the duplicate flag. I removed the bounty since it was only a few hours old and closed it accordingly – note that there's no benefit from having the answer duplicated *again*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the case where Windows destroyed its own font data, you could :

1. Get the contents of `C:\Windows\Fonts` from another PC
2. Copy these fonts into a temporary folder
3. Use regedit to delete (after saving) the contents of
   `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Fonts`
4. Reboot
5. Copy the fonts into `C:\Windows\Fonts`
6. Re-install the fonts by opening Control Panel / Fonts,
   and from the File menu select 'Install New Fonts...' and add the fonts
   *from the temporary folder*.

Comment: 4 hours till I can award bounty.

Answer (score 1):

Your best solution for this problem is probably Windows Refresh.

To 'Refresh' your computer, follow the instructions below quoted from http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/restore-refresh-reset-pc.

```
To refresh your PC

Swipe in from the right edge of the screen, tap Settings, and then tap Change PC settings.
(If you're using a mouse, point to the upper-right corner of the screen, move the mouse pointer down, click Settings, and then click Change PC settings.)

Tap or click Update and recovery, and then tap or click Recovery.

Under Refresh your PC without affecting your files, tap or click Get started.

Follow the instructions on the screen
```

Your files and everything SHOULD still be there, but **any programs installed may vanish (but windows says that there will be a list of all programs removed on your computer).**

Good luck with your computer. Hope this helps! (if it does, don't forget to accept it as an answer)

Comment: This was one of the first things I thought to try. I apparently didn't have System restore on. I did try to do a "Refresh" (Not sure what that is yet.) However, the "refresh" failed. I'd have to try again to see what the error message was. (Sorry I didn't put that I tried that in the question.)

Comment: That's alright. Have you turned System Restore on and tried again? This may save you a lot of time and trouble if you try the simplest solution first (System Restore).

Comment: Turning now System Restore on is too late. But as Refresh cannot fail, better specify in your post what you did.

Comment: @harrymc I misunderstood how System Restore worked on Windows 8.1 and changed it to Refresh in my answer.

Comment: Sorry bout that.

Comment: Attention: Refresh will wipe out all non-Metro installed applications.

Comment: @harrymc I put that in my answer already (before you said it).

Comment: Nope, it's my comment that predates your edit by 4 minutes (good idea of yours to add this warning in).

Comment: @harrymc My edit put it in bold. Quote: `Emboldifyed important things`