# How to fix the down arrow icon in Windows 8.1 start screen?

Tags: windows-8.1, fonts, start-screen

I am using `Windows 8.1` and the down arrow button in the start screen, that takes you to the `Apps` screen, has a misplaced font file, and is showing a box instead of down arrow. This happened after I installed my fonts (probably 100+ fonts) and don't know specifically which font did this. I removed all these new fonts but the icon was still not fixed. Before answering please note that the `Wingdings` font is installed and I didn't changed anything regarding it. Can somebody tell me where exactly the problem is? Or how to fix it?

Comment: Try using DISM to repair the damage

Comment: possible duplicate of [Windows 8.1 missing font files after restart](http://superuser.com/questions/695635/windows-8-1-missing-font-files-after-restart)

Comment: install such a huge number of fonts globally might not be a good idea. If you just want to use it in some apps like Photoshop for artistic purposes then it's better to use that app's local font feature