# Installed a font from a Mac OS X computer now all Windows icons and tray texts look funny

Tags: windows-8, windows-8.1, fonts

I am running windows 8.1.

I installed a font Avenir Next‎ which I got from a friend who has a Macintosh. I guess that’s the reason, I am not entirely sure. But my fonts in the tray and on the desktop look unreadable weird:

[image]

As well as in some applications like Greenshot and the Windows clock

[image]

Now, I should uninstall the font, right?

Well if I go to Windows Explorer: shell:fonts
I get this any ideas what to do?

[image]

Comment: Try searching for *Font settings* and clicking the [Restore](http://i.stack.imgur.com/ufehf.jpg) button.

Answer (score 1):

basically two things were needed. Number one was getting the fonts:
(from:
http://www.withsteps.com/2621/windows-8-default-font-download-repair-kit.html )

> Windows 8 Default Font Download – Repair Kit A long time ago I’ve
>   offered you a simple solution on how to restore your default fonts in
>   Windows 7. The basic idea is that you can get in real problems if your
>   default system fonts get messed up. For example, when you install too
>   many fonts or even worst, when you allow other software to replace
>   your fonts. In this cases, your explorer, your browser, your games and
>   basically everything on your computer can show strange characters and
>   bad font style.
>
> To repair this error I recommend to restore all your fonts:
>
> 1. Go to C:\Windows\Fonts (where C:\ is my Windows drive) and delete as much fonts as you can. (ctrl+a to select all and delete key to
>      delete … skipped where the system couldn’t remove the files)
> 2. Download the default Font folder : [Windows 8 Default Font Folder](http://www.withsteps.com/download/2646/)
> 3. Extract the content of that folder.
> 4. Select all the files in the extracted folder (ctrl+a)
> 5. Right click and select Install

number two was making the fonts STAY after restart, and not getting erased again:

[Windows 8.1 missing font files after restart](https://superuser.com/questions/695635/windows-8-1-missing-font-files-after-restart)

Answer (score 0):

Uh oh.. it looks like whatever font you tried to install apparently deleted *all* of your fonts!

Don't panic, though! In order to get them back, try running `sfc /scannow` in Command Prompt to verify your Windows files. Hopefully, this should replace the missing font files and tell you what it detected.

Be sure to be wary of malicious "font installers" next time.

Comment: If something deleted all fonts, which font is used to display those strange symbols?

Comment: @Dennis Marlett. The same behavior can be seen in Windows XP. It cannot be uninstalled because it is used by the system for window buttons.

Comment: OK, that makes sense.

Comment: this didnt help