# Windows 8.1 missing font registry and fonts not working on startup

Tags: windows-8.1, windows-registry, fonts

After installing some terrible fonts, my Windows 8.1 laptop has been having the weird symbols on startup problem detailed [here](https://superuser.com/questions/695635/windows-8-1-missing-font-files-after-restart), and while I've copied the font files over from another computer, my computer actually seems to be [completely missing the font registry](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iIaCg.png) "\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Fonts" which both good answers there say to delete. Rebooting has not rebuilt a registry; system restores to earlier points pre-bad fonts have failed.

Having copied fonts over, my font files are still in the folder on startup, but apart from a few select fonts including SegoeUI and Terminal, can't be selected in any programs until I've reinstalled them (right click Install), upon which the "already installed, would you like to reinstall?" alert pops up, and that results in duplicate font files (eg. "verdana_0.ttf" being the duplicate of "verdana.ttf") in the folder.

SegoeUI also takes a minute or two to kick in and only does so after logging in, meaning characters in the Windows login password box are still squares and system text shows as nonsense characters for a moment after login.

How do I restore this missing registry? I am hoping that this would help solve the missing/not sticking fonts problem.

Comment: I am having this exact problem :/