# System fonts not working in Windows 8.1

Tags: windows-8.1, fonts

Yesterday evening I returned to my PC and it had shut down and upon restarting, something was wrong with the fonts. All the icons on my desktop showed up correctly, but the text under each one was in some crazy, wingdings-ish font with checkmarks, rectangles, arrows...

And dialog boxes are all rectangles instead of text. See attached image. I also tried reinstalling Segoe UI font as suggested on one forum. Thanks.
[image]

I'm also checking this post, as it appears related: [Windows 8.1 missing font files after restart](https://superuser.com/questions/695635/windows-8-1-missing-font-files-after-restart)

Comment: How many files do you have in c:\windows\fonts? (assuming windows is installed to c:\windows)

Comment: Three. Fixedsys Regular, System Bold, And terminal (bold and regular)

Comment: Should be like 100+... if you dir/s *.ttf and/or .fon from cmd assuming path is c:\> are they all in another directory?

Comment: OK. Checking. When I do that in cmd a lot of the data scroll up past the limit that I can scroll up to so I can only see a lot of Adobe and recycle bin directories. I'll see if I can get the font directory.

Comment: try piping to a file to read the results

c:\>dir/s *.ttf > c:\fonts.log then open up fonts.log (assuming you can read it)

Comment: So, it's taking awhile for that output to write to file. But I've been reading the file as it builds and nothing except for backups of old harddrives so far. However, I dropped in seguisym.ttf into C:\windows\fonts and this seems to have fixed my problem with my display. I fear there is a bigger problem underlying this though, that caused all the fonts in the font directory to disappear.

Comment: Also a big list of fonts installed to ....\Microsoft Office\root\vfs\Fonts\private and Program Files \ TexPoint\fonts\outline

Comment: Update your question

Comment: First check for disk errors: right click disk icon->Properties->Tools->Check. Next start Command Prompt (CMD) as Administrator and enter `sfc /scannow` so Windows would try repair broken files. To start CMD just enter it in search field. If it would be imposible to right click it and selecting "Run as administrator", run it and pin to taskbar, then close and right click pinned icon. This time menu should contain "Run as Administrator".